# Django Forms from Models

Tags: python, django, forms, model, creation

I am trying to integrate an app called [Django-Classifieds](https://github.com/saebyn/django-classifieds), but am having trouble figuring out how to manipulate some of the elements.

The app allows one to create a category and subfields through the admin section, which will be displayed and allow the user to create a post within said category. Although the Django admin allows one to create fields:

[image: DJango Admin]

And writes them to the database:

[image]

I cannot figure out how to call these fields and display them to the user. Currently, only the title field is displayed. I understand that using ModelForm will allow me access to these elements, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it with BaseForm (used by in the app as below):

```
class AdForm(BaseForm):
  def __init__(self, instance, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
                         initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=':',
                         empty_permitted=False):

    self.instance = instance
    object_data = ad_to_dict(self.instance)
    self.declared_fields = SortedDict()
    self.base_fields = fields_for_ad(self.instance)

    # if initial was provided, it should override the values from instance
    if initial is not None:
        object_data.update(initial)

    BaseForm.__init__(self, data, files, auto_id, prefix, object_data,
                      error_class, label_suffix, empty_permitted)

  def save(self, commit=True):
    if not commit:
        raise NotImplementedError("AdForm.save must commit it's changes.")

    if self.errors:
        raise ValueError("The ad could not be updated because the data didn't validate.")

    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

    # save fieldvalues for self.instance
    fields = field_list(self.instance)

    for field in fields:
        if field.enable_wysiwyg:
            value = unicode(stripHTML(cleaned_data[field.name]))
        else:
            value = unicode(cleaned_data[field.name])

        # strip words in settings.FORBIDDEN_WORDS
        for word in settings.FORBIDDEN_WORDS:
            value = value.replace(word, '')

        # title is stored directly in the ad, unlike all other editable fields
        if field.name == 'title':
            self.instance.title = value
            self.instance.save()
        else:
            # check to see if field.fieldvalue_set has a value with ad=self.instance
            try:
                # if it does, update
                fv = field.fieldvalue_set.get(ad=self.instance)
            except FieldValue.DoesNotExist:
                # otherwise, create a new one
                fv = field.fieldvalue_set.create(ad=self.instance)

            # XXX some ugly price fixing
            if field.name.endswith('price'):
                m = re.match('^\$?(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?)*\d{3}(\.\d{0,2})?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,2}?)$', value)
                value = m.group(1)
                value.replace(',', '')
                value = '%.2f' % float(value)

            fv.value = value
            fv.save()

    return self.instance
```

How can I display all created fields in the `AdForm` above?

Any examples appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorporating ModelForm isn't needed, since the purpose of the AdForm class is to allow access to those fields. In order to display the custom fields added to a category in the database, all that is needed is to add the fields to the templates for the appropriate category (assuming you are using the views provided in the app). There are examples of this in the "base" category templates within the classifieds app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @Saebyn. Would you mind helping me understand the correct `{{ variable }}` name to use in template to access the form fields from the database (for a description field, for example)?

Comment: You should be able to do `{{ form.Descripion }}`. Note that the case of the field name should match the case of the field name in the database. Which version of Django are you using? There may be issues with the master branch of the project for more recent versions of Django. I had been working on a branch to support Django 1.3, so you might want to look there.

Comment: I have been using Django 1.4, but will look to 1.3 and the branch you suggested. Thank you very much for your insights.